# Dynamic value in application template

Tags: ember.js

I tried to implement user name displaying after log in. It displays in top menu. But top menu is getting displayed before log in, so it user name is getting cached.

I tried many approaches, and using volatile() is seems the best option, but it doesn't work. In this simple example currentTime calculates only once:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    {{currentTime}}
</script>

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  currentTime: function() {
    console.log('computing value');
    var time = new Date();
    return time;
  }.property().volatile()
});
```

Ember version 1.3

P.S. I prepared the gist to illustrate this issue: http://jsbin.com/OPUSoTaF/1

Actually, I can't find ANY way do display dynamic value in Ember's application template. Tried to display value from another controller using `{{render}}` helper, value still gets cached.

Comment: Where and how are you storing the username value? Your example property is only executing once because the computed property isn't watching any properties. The value returned will only update when the watched property changes. See http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/

Comment: I'm using a `localStorage`. Suppose I can't watch it, so I need to prevent caching some other way.

Comment: For the template, I would use a value stored in your controller, and populate that from localStorage on init, if present. You just have to update localStore on login/logout.

Comment: Which controller to store value in? It seems that `init()` gets called only once on each controller: http://jsbin.com/OPUSoTaF/2/edit

Comment: Save it wherever it makes sense in your app. You can save it in applicationController, or loginController (might make more sense), and use the needs api (http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/) to be able to access the actual value in loginController from applicationController. Yes, init() is only called once. Route controllers are persistent singletons, so they are created once, and are still available, even if you're on another route.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I just need to update value on ApplicationController from some other controller, and to do it in a proper way. Like this:

```
App.LoginController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: 'application',
  setTime: function() {
    this.get('controllers.application').set('currentTime', new Date());
  }
});
```

The application to illustrate: http://jsbin.com/OPUSoTaF/4/edit

Answer (score 0):

You can change ember properties and thus views using Handlebars [`{{action 'actionName'}}`](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/) helper. You can add action helper to almost any UI element in your handlebars template an it is usually triggered on click. When triggered it calls `actionName` method on the controller.

**Example:**
Handlebars template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
  <button {{action 'login'}}>Login</button>
  {{loginTime}}
</script>
```

Controller:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  loginTime: 'User not logged in yet',

  actions: {
    login: function() {
      // ... Do some login stuff ...
      this.set('loginTime', new Date());
    }
  }
});
```

Working jsbin example is here: http://jsbin.com/udUyOXaL/1/edit

Comment: Nice. You can o it that way. Just in case you are interested, it is also possible to trigger actions remotely with `this.get('controllers.application').send('login')`